# Adicionar plugins javascript no angular 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular-7, dados-hierárquicos

Estou tentando montar um gráfico de hierarquia na página usando um [plugin](https://github.com/dabeng/ng-orgchart) de Angular a partir deste tutorial. Mesmo olhando o [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-orgchart-demo) e tentando colocar os desse mesmo jeito

Quando carrego a página, a página não funciona...

Desse jeito:

```
<organization-chart [datasource]="ds"></organization-chart>
```

Não dá erro, mas quando clico no rota onde se encontra a página, a rota não carrega, mas quando tiro o component, do plugin a rota volta a funcionar

Mas esse mesmo gráfico de organização eu consegui carregar usando o html com javascript e jquery,

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tem como eu usar essa mesma estratégia?

De carregar os plugins javascript e css no angular já que o componente não funciona?

Esse foi o jeito que eu consegui montar esse gráfico de organização em JQuery com javascript e css do plugin

```
const buscarDados = () => {

        $.ajax({
           url: "{{ route('medidor.hierarquia') }}",
           type: "get",
           dataType: "json"
        }).done( r => {
            mountHieraquy(r)
            /*setTimeout(() => {
                buscarDados()
            }, 5000);*/
        })
    }
    const mountHieraquy = ( obj ) => {
        $('#chart-container').html('')

        $('#chart-container').orgchart({
                    data:obj,
                    visibleLevel: 2,
                    nodeTemplate: nodeTemplate,
                    //zoom: true,
                    pan: true

             }) 

$('.ip_medidor').on('click', function(){
            const ip = $(this).data('ip')
            sessionStorage.setItem('medidor', ip)
            sessionStorage.setItem('opcao', 1)
            sessionStorage.setItem('errorCount', 0)
            //location.href= ; 
            const url = ip.indexOf("120") != -1 ? "{{ route('medidor.sepam') }}" : "{{ route('medicao.monitoramento') }}"
            window.open( url, '_blank');
        })       

}
```

Como link e estilo próprio

Existe uma forma que possa levar esse código para o Angular?

Os arquivos que eu adicionei foram

- html2cancas.min.js
- jquery.orgchart.js
- jquery.orgchart.min.js
- jquery.orgcart.css
- jquery.orgchart.min.css

Comment: Cada caso é um caso, só testando mesmo. Mas, o import dos arquivos pode ser feito normalmente colocando-os dentro da tag **scripts** no arquivo `angular.json` não?!

Comment: aI como eu faria a função acima no componente?

Comment: Retira o **const** e a **arrow function** da função e declara ela normalmente no componente: **`buscarDados()  {...`**

Comment: Com o todo esse jquery também?

Comment: Sim, a função não usa jQuery? jQuery, Typescript é tudo Javascript!

Comment: Realmente, deu certo! Por favor, adiciona a resposta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom só para deixar registrado como resposta aqui no site para futuras pesquisas sobre o assunto. Para a utilização de bibliotecas **JavaScript** em projetos **`Angular`** além do uso de links por CDN na index da aplicação, "pelas boa práticas do framework" o mais indicado é que esses scripts sejam instalados (npm ,yarn, etc...) se possível e declarados no arquivo **angular.json** dentro da tag `scripts`.

Exemplo de importação da biblioteca jQuery:

```
"scripts": [
   "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
]
```

Obtendo assim o seu acesso e utilização globalmente em toda aplicação Angular:

```
ngOnInit() {
  $(() => {
    console.log('jQuery funcionando') // dispara o log na iniciação do componente
  })
}
```

**EDIT :** Se possuir os arquivos das bibliotecas basta inseri-los no diretório **assets** e indicar o caminho no arquivo **`angular.json`**.

Comment: eu coloque no assets o que eu precisa e chamei no arquivo angular.json

Comment: Assim, vc tem as bibliotecas em arquivos, aí inseriu esses arquivos no assets e declarou no angular.json, realmente esqueci dessa possibilidade também, vou editar a resposta.